# Page redirect in rule after VBO new custom operation is is not redirecting

Tags: 7, commerce

I need to page redirect after the VBO operation.

The page redirects is inside a rule component that I have created for a new operation in VBO.
This is the my new operation in my VBO:
[image]

I have marked force redirect. And it doesn't work too.
I tested installing rules debug, to see if rules was executed, and it shows as executed, but it doesn't redirect to cart.
What could I check on this issue?

The debug is showing, skipping page redirect during the batching process, see it please.

[image]

How could I add a rule for page redirect, just after the batch process of my VBO operation? This could works.

Note: Not very relevant but

### Here is the export of the rule:

{
 "rules_vbo_add_to_cart" :

```
"LABEL" : "A\u00f1adir las fotos seleccionadas al carrito",
"PLUGIN" : "action set",
"OWNER" : "rules",
"REQUIRES" : [ "commerce_cart", "rules" ],
"ACCESS_EXPOSED" : "1",
"USES VARIABLES" : { "commerce_product" : { "label" : "Commerce product", "type" : "commerce_product" } },
"ACTION SET" : [
  { "commerce_cart_product_add_by_sku" : {
      "USING" : {
        "user" : [ "site:current-user" ],
        "sku" : [ "commerce-product:sku" ],
        "quantity" : "1",
        "combine" : "1"
      },
      "PROVIDE" : { "product_add_line_item" : { "product_add_line_item" : "Added product line item" } }
    }
  },
  { "redirect" : { "url" : "\/cart" } }
]
```

}

### }

Comment: pasting an export of your rule would help.

Comment: Please check recent log messages.

Comment: exported the rule, and edited the question to clarify!

Answer (score 0):

There could be a possibility that some other redirect rule is overriding you **page redirect to cart** Rule. So please check if in case any other rule is getting triggered or not. If yes, then set priority of **page redirect to cart** rule's **high**.

1. For checking if any other rule is overriding the "Page redirect to Cart"  rule we can actually use
   `watchdog('Backtrack message','<pre>'.print_r(debug_backtrack(),true).'</pre>');`
   It will give show everything what all code running at the time the rule triggers.
2. You are absolutely correct sir, just need to set the weight of **Page Redirect to Cart** rule lower than other rule. It will set the priority higher.

Comment: Thank you Gaurav, 
1. How could I check if any other rule is overriding my page redirect?.
2. Set priority of page redirect rule high means less the weight of rule?

Comment: Thank you Gaurav, where do I execute your watchdog line?. I tried to run it in devel -> run php code, and it gives me error Fatal error: Call to undefined function debug_backtrack() in /home1/bunset/public_html/tienda/sites/all/modules/devel/devel.module(1415) : eval()'d code on line 1

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution on how to do a custom page redirect, after an VBO Operation.

Here there is a patch to add a custom redirect field in the options
https://www.drupal.org/node/2307381

I have applied the patch #6

in ./profiles/commerce_kickstart/modules/contrib/views_bulk_operations

using the command

patch < 2307381_6.patch

It asked me for file to patch, and I had to indicate:

file to patch: ./views/views_bulk_operations_handler_field_operations.inc

then patch done!.

Results is awesome and redirect specified is working perfectly!! so I am happy!

[image]

Thanks for all your help!!